# Why (MNIST trained) model is not good at digits which not in the center of the picture

Tags: deep-learning, mnist

#### About the problem

My CNN model has accuracy up to 99.4% on the MNIST dataset. So I try some irregular input. And the predicted result is not correct.

The following are some of the irregular input I use

[image]

[image]

As we know, CNN convolution will scan the whole image, also don't care about the key features in which areas of the image.

**Why CNN could not deal with irregular input**

Comment: Did you also train with these irregular inputs?

Comment: Of course not. I just want to know CNN can solve this translation of the images

Comment: It can, but MNIST is too simple for what you are trying to do. More variability in the training set is needed to obtain such invariances.

Comment: I also think so. According to you, isn't it at the time of training model, the model is also studied the digital position, I understand it right?

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place to ask for aimless suggestions. Consider checking out the Help Center to know what questions are on-topic here and [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm doing better, at the same time, very thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we know, CNN convolution will scan the whole image, also don't care about the key features in which areas of the image.

This is simply false. CNN do not "scan" image, a single filter can be seen as scanning, but the whole network does not. CNN is composed of many layers, which will eventually reduce amount of information, and at some point also use location-specific feature (in final fully connected layers, in some global averaging and so on). Consequently, while CNNs are robust to **small** perturbations (translations or noise, but not rotations!), they are not **invariant** to these transformations. In other words - moving an image 3 pixels to the left is fine, but trying to classify a number in completely different scale/position will fail because there is nothing forcing your model to be invariant to that. Some models that indeed learn these kind of invariances are **Spatial Transformers Networks**, but CNNs simply don't.

Comment: if we have a convolution operator from a neural network f(x) then applying it to f(T(x)) where T is translation, will not result in the same outcome. If one were to add some specific agglomeration, such as maximum, then indeed max_pixel f(x) = max_pixel f(T(x)) (up to border effects). In other words, it has "same effect throughout the signal", but "the position of the result" shifts. If one was to apply only convolution operations, and global agglomerations, and was working on a sphere (or other manifold without 'border') one would have really translation invariant model by construction.